# Azure Active Directory B2C - Maintaining Users in the Database

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm transforming a legacy system that stores its users in a database (including credentials) to use Azure AD B2C for authentication.

My first step is to rewrite the frontal API (the API that serves the web client directly)

Because many other systems and database tables depend on the users table and its columns, I've decided on creating a db user for every new azure ad registration.

This is the problem, the user id in the database is the primary key, an auto incremented number.

The id that I extract from the access token claims is a ad object identifier, a GUID.

To be able to relate an ad b2c user entity to a database user entity, I will have to create a new column in the users table, AzureObjectId.

The problem is that now I would have to constantly do the conversion between AzureObjectId which I extract from the access token, to the database users id, because other database tables and other internal APIs that I access expect a database user id.

What would be the right way to tackle this?
What I can thinks of is

1. Transforming AzureObjectId to database user id during every interaction with the database or another internal API.
2. Once my API creates the database user, use the Azure AD B2C Graph API to add a new claim, database user id, to the user.

Both of these I want to avoid.
Is there someway to enrich the access token with the database user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with second option as its a one time operation and system doesn't need to do the conversion every time.

#### Update with details

This seems to be a [migration scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) as well.  Check samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration#just-in-time-migration)

You will also need to use [Restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw) feature of custom policies as well.

During the signup process, execute a restful technical profile which will call an api in contoso (your) service to create user. The contoso service will return the database user id of the newly created user. This new userId can be used as a subsequent claim for the user and AzureADB2C will create the user with that extension property.

The another approach is what we discussed earlier. After signup the user can be created by the service and for the first call, service can insert a claim for itself with new database user Id.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. However, it feels to me like a workaround rather than an organic solution. From what I understand, the graph API is more suited for administrative operations, like migrations, so I don't feel entirely confident in putting it in production code.

Comment: That's not necessary from documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

'A primary example is user management. You might need to migrate an existing user store to a B2C tenant. You may want to host user registration on your own page and create user accounts in your Azure AD B2C directory behind the scenes. These types of tasks require the ability to create, read, update, and delete user accounts. You can do these tasks by using the Azure AD Graph API.'

Comment: The use of Graph api is recommended in many cases where the regular flows cannot do the job.

Comment: Okay, so how would it work? A user sends a request to my API with an access token, I create an equivalent db user, add a db user id claim via graph api. But what would I do about the existing token? I would have to ask the re-authenticate in order to create a new token that contains the db user id claim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use [custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes)

You can add custom attributes via the portal and select these to return them as claims in the token.

The Graph API link above shows how to create them programmatically.

So if you populate the database user id into the custom attribute you'll be able to return it in the token.

Comment: You mean using the graph API to update the claims problematically after I create the user in the database, right? This might be a good solution, but what do I do with the current access token after I've updated the claims via graph API? Do I ask the user to re-authenticate in order to get a new token?

Comment: Yes - I'm wondering if getting a new token via the refresh token flow will result in an updated token?

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you for the answer.